# How to Login Desktop app to website in gmail like Gtalk

Tags: authentication, gmail

I have app and i want to implemet direct gmail login using google authenitcation token like gtalk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are looking for [this](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/openid_reference_implementation.html).
You also may check [this](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) out.